# Consulting an array into a DB and comparing with a ID SQL Typescript

Tags: sql, typescript

Hello I'm trying to take data from a sql table but the data that I want to check is into an array, so I need compare the data to check if an user is into the group, the array only have the IDs from users and the specific ID that I want is being bringing to me through the login.

This code is in Typescript.

If you need more information let me know please.

```
class CompanyController {
    async consultCompanys(req: Request, res: Response) {
        let response: ResponseModel = new ResponseModel(ECodeResponse.Ok, "", []);
        const { UserId } = req.body;
        
        try {
    
          const Companies: any  = await pool.query(
            `SELECT (CompanyId) From Companies Where Members = '${UserId}'`
          );
    
    
          response.Code = ECodeResponse.Ok;
          response.Message = EWarningMessage.Error;
          return res.json(response);
    
        } catch (error) {
            response.Code = ECodeResponse.Warning;
            response.Message = EWarningMessage.Error;
            return res.json(response);
        }
      }

}
```

I'm a litle oxidated in this kind of consults

Comment: Which DBMS? In SQL Server you can pass a Table-Valued Parameter

Comment: @Charlieface `SELECT CompanyId FROM Companies WHERE Members IN ('${UserId}');`
something like that?

Comment: No, the param is a table: `Members IN (SELECT val FROM @param)`. Which DBMS are you using? Please answer this

Comment: Is `Members` by any chance a comma-separated list all concatenated together